# laravel Closed without sending a request; it was probably just an unused speculative preconnection

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

i'm new to laravel/lumen framework, following this article: https://omojolasamsonade.medium.com/laravel-8-how-to-create-restful-apis-with-lumen-8-8859960bfac8
i'm trying to set up a rest api server.
i can connect to database and retrieve users and single user information. the problem is i can't create an user, i have this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (john, john@john.com, 2021-01-29 14:34:42, 2021-01-29 14:34:42))
```

and in the server console i have

```
[Fri Jan 29 15:34:42 2021] [::1]:5100 Accepted
[Fri Jan 29 15:34:42 2021] [::1]:5101 Accepted
[Fri Jan 29 15:34:42 2021] [::1]:5100 Closed without sending a request; it was probably just an unused speculative preconnection
[Fri Jan 29 15:34:42 2021] [::1]:5100 Closing
[Fri Jan 29 15:34:43 2021] [::1]:5101 [500]: POST /api/v1/users/add
[Fri Jan 29 15:34:43 2021] [::1]:5101 Closing
```

BUT in the user model i didn't define the `updated_at`, `created_at` fields, just name and email, neither i have them in db, i think laravel adds automatically these fields.
someone could help me? thanks

Comment: yes Eloquent automatically handles those time stamp fields, the docs will tell you how to disbable this if needed completely, or modify the timestamp names or if they are used at all, etc

Comment: ok, thanks @lagbox, i will check

Comment: now it works, but in the console i have always the error [Fri Jan 29 15:53:57 2021] [::1]:5823 Closed without sending a request; it was probably just an unused speculative preconnection